Postgres sort order results in different orders for different clients
Azure DB for Postgres flexible server
I have Azure DB for Postgres flexible server. I have created a database in this server with en_US.utf8 collation. In this database I have created a table with column 'id' data type varchar.
While connecting to pgadmin and running the order by clause on id column it results in the following order:

-1, 1, +1

Where as running the same query connecting to psql inside docker application it results in different order:

+1, 1, -1

Ask: Why this is occurring.
And how could I resolve this behaviour of unexpected ordering in the docker application to result in same as pgadmin.

Are you really still running Postgres 9?

No DDL, no content, no queries. We can now only guess that your queries or DDL are different. And if you're still on version 9, you have bigger problems than just the sort order.

There is no version 9. We'd need your exact version number too.
